# Calling php functions from dynamicaly added content using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to call php page using $.load() the problem is that I have php code (function call ) in the called page .

//fuctions.php

```
<?php 

funcion print_sum(){

echo $sum}


?>
```

the second page 
//index.php

```
require_once(function.php);
```

script

```
$(fucntion(){

$.load(content.php , function(){});

});
```

script

//third page is the content

```
<div>

<?php print_sum()?>

</div>
```

I'm expecting it to use the functions in the page loaded in but it didn't recognize the function

Comment: in `content.php` page, you actually need `require_once(function.php);`

Comment: **DON'T USE** names like **function**, even if it's a name of file.

Comment: Also, it's spelled `function`, not `funcion` or `fuctions` or `fucntion`, so you're going to have errors everywhere.

Comment: On the third Page `print_r (get_defined_functions ());` command. If the function doesn't write the name, there is a problem including it on the page.